# Search for column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do you search if a value exist in a specific row?

Example I have this file which contains the following:

```
ID      Name
1       Mark
2       John
3       Mary
```

The user will input 1 and it will

```
print("the value already exist.")
```

But if the user input 4 it will add a new row containing 4 and

```
name = input('Name')
```

and update the file like this

```
    ID      Name
    1       Mark
    2       John
    3       Mary
    4       (userinput)
```

Comment: IDs are index? When updating the given ID, what should be done to other columns of the dataframe?

Comment: `df['column_name'].isin(['id']).any()` should tell if the 'ID' is in the column or not (output will be `True` or `False`). If `True`, do nothing, else create a new row with the user's input.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of your data and what result you expect. It isn't clear from your question exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy approach will be:

```
import pandas as pd
bool_val = False
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    if str(df.iloc[i]['ID']) == str(input_str):
        bool_val = False
        break
        
    else:
        print("there")
        bool_val = True
if bool_val == True:
    df = df.append(pd.Series([input_str, name], index = ['ID', 'Name']), ignore_index=True)
```

Remember to add the parameter ignore_index to avoid TypeError. I added a bool value to avoid appending a row multiple times.

Comment: In the new_row Series, just add another element like: new_row = pd.Series([ID, name]). This should work. ID is the input ID from the user and name is again the name entered by the user.

Comment: im getting an invalid syntax in the "if df.iloc[i]['ID'] = input_str:" line

Comment: try if str(df.iloc[i]['ID']) == str(input_str). Just to clarify, input_str is the ID input by the user.

Comment: got this error TypeError: append() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_text'

Comment: I am so sorry. it is 'ignore_index'. Try now and it should work!! Let me know if there is still some error.

Comment: btw for the new input should i change new_row = pd.Series([input_str]) to new_row = pd.Series([ID][Name])?

Comment: No. it should be 1 list like: new_row = pd.Series([ID, name])

Comment: because im getting this error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: Got it there were already no error except that when  i printed the file it didnt append the new row

Comment: i also tried adding df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False) it still didnt append

Comment: I editied my answer. Basically we weren't saving the update to the data frame. we need to do df = df.operation()

Comment: How do you do that? should i put df = df.operation() in the last line?

Comment: Check my edited answer. That should work properly. If it does please upvote my answer!!

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hi sorry for the bother. Yesterday it was already workingidk what happened but everytime i input ID that exist in the file it executes if bool_val == True

Comment: Please check out the edit. Adding a break statement and changing the bool_value to false if ID found does the job. Do mark my answer as accepted if it works for you!!

Answer (score 2):

```
searchid=20 #use sys.argv[1] if needed to be passed as argument to the program. Or read it as raw_input
if str(searchid) in df.index.astype(str):
      print("ID found")
else:
      name=raw_input("ID not found. Specify the name for this ID to update the data:") #use input() if python version >= 3
      df.loc[searchid]=[str(name)]
```

If ID is not index:

```
if str(searchid) in df.ID.values.astype(str):
      print("ID found")
else:
      name=raw_input("ID not found. Specify the name for this ID to update the data:") #use input() if python version >= 3
      df.loc[searchid]=[str(searchid),str(name)]
```

specifying column headers to update during df update might avoid errors of mismatch:

```
df.loc[searchid]={'ID': str(searchid), 'Name': str(name)}
```

This should help

Also read at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html, that mentions the inherent nature of append and concat to copy the full dataframe.

Comment: ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns

Comment: the above assumed that ID column you specified is index. Do df.ID.values in if statement and df.loc[searchid]=[searchid,name] in else statement if ID is not index. Also use str(searchid) based on datatype of ID column in [str(searchid),name]

Comment: @SinClair check the edited answer as per previous comment

Comment: df.loc[searchid]={'ID': str(searchid), 'Name': str(name)}

Comment: All three versions work perfectly at my end. I could have suggested append in the else statement just to get accepted answer, but that's not what I see as optimal at my end...

Answer (score 1):

`df.loc['ID']` will return the row containing the ID in the index of the dataframe. Assuming IDs are the index values of the df you are referring to.

If you have a list of IDs and wish to search for them all together then:

assuming:

```
listofids=['ID1','ID2','ID3']
df.loc[listofids]
```

will yield the rows containing the above IDs

**If IDs are not in index then:**
Assuming `df['ids']` contain the given ID list:

```
'searchedID' in df.ids.values
```

will return True or False based on presence or absence